# how can you fix the timed out after 300 seconds of waiting for emulator to come online problem

Tags: android-studio

When I attempt to load up the emulator, the bar will fill but when it loads fully it just disappears and after 300 seconds sends me this
[image]
does anyone know how to fix this I cant find anything that works

I've looked online and tried a few solutions but none of them seemed to work, I had changed the graphics to software, tried creating different phone types and dried cold booting but nothing has worked and gave me the same error every time I am very new to this so I don't know a solution